# Linux view log file, that each time recreated

Tags: linux, logging, vim

I am currently working on Linux with tmux + vim.
What is the proper way to view log files, that each time recreated?

I am using Check as unit test framework for C, and after make check, log file recreated. Vim doesn't shows this changes, or maybe **:set autoreload** doesnt't work for me.

Comment: I too had this problem. Logs get updated within several seconds in my case and hence I used to create and call a function which opens the updated file every 10 seconds, for example. The answer for this question will help me as well.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/1157410

Comment: If you are running `make check`, why not running it from vim  with `:make` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Vim-Timer` plugin available in GitHub. This allows the user to set a time interval and the file is reloaded after that time interval. (Time interval is less than a second by default, but you can change it)

It is available at https://github.com/dahu/Vim-Timer

After installing the plugin, put the code in autoread_updater.vim into `~/.vimrc`.

It works perfectly for autoread though there are minor bugs.

Comment: Thanks, 
I also thinks that should be true Unix-style solution, like "tail -f".